# Convert time ago to its date time

Tags: php

I wonder if it possible to convert `time ago` to `date time`

for example `5 years, 9 months, 1 week, 5 days ago` to `2013-05-01`

i've been using this `function` to convert `date` to `time ago` but how to do the reverse!

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```

Usage :

```
echo time_elapsed_string('2013-05-01', true);
// 5 years, 9 months, 1 week, 5 days, 23 hours, 17 minutes, 54 seconds ago
```

Comment: something like `echo (new DateTime)->modify('-5 years -9 months -1 week -5 days')-format('Y-m-d');`  [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2640b3ed890016beaade3d3b4a701bab2c19fa6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not you can do this:

```
//uses and modifies today's date 2019-02-13
$date = (new DateTime)->modify('-5 years -9 months -1 week -5 days')->format('Y-m-d');

echo $date."\n";

//takes the modified data and does the reverse
$date = (new DateTime($date))->modify('+5 years +9 months +1 week +5 days')->format('Y-m-d');

echo $date."\n";
```

Output

```
2013-05-01
2019-02-13 //today
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0f806b485a9cfb88305492d8f50bc37628497bb)

As long as you create that string to comply to relative date formats,

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

I don't see why you couldn't plug it back into the datetime class.